# How to reuse webpack vendor bundle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, code-splitting

I assume that I can achieve what I am trying to do with webpack but still could not figure it out. Here is the use case.

I have couple of Angular Apps (will get loaded within same browser window) which will be reusing exactly the same vendor bundle. At the moment webpack produces two files, app.[app_module_name].js and vendor.js in each app. So theoretically I should be able to **only include one vendor.js file** in the html page and then load several app modules. However this does does not work since webpack internal references for lib's in vendor are different from each other.

Following is my configuration at the moment. Would be great if anyone can help me out.

```
entry: {
      bootstrap: './src/app/init/bootstrap.js',
      tradingApp: './src/app/app.js'
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      publicPath: '/',
      path: path.join(projectRoot, 'dist')
    },
plugins:[
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        minChunks: function (module) {
          return module.resource && module.resource.indexOf(path.join(projectRoot, 'src')) === -1
        }
      }),
]
```

Comment: That's the reason to build the apps together, so they could reuse the 'vendor' chunk.

Comment: @estus each application get build in a different timeline. E.g. App A will be deployed to production monthly and App B get deploy to production weekly. However regardless of the timeline vendor package is always same

Comment: It depends on how you manage your projects, but you could build A from its 'release' branch every time (it still has to be deployed weekly). I guess that the alternative is to fix module ids (with [records](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#recordspath-recordsinputpath-recordsoutputpath) or [ChunkManifestPlugin](https://github.com/diurnalist/chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin)), so only B will be changed on build. I don't think that there's a way to 'only include one vendor.js file in the html page', except by exporting vendor modules to globals, Webpack doesn't work like that.

Comment: @estus Thanks for the suggestion. I have change the build pipeline which builds all the modules regardless there is a change or not. Then build process validate checksum of each file and if there is a change then only deploy the file to production

Comment: Is it possible to reuse bundles, such as the mentioned vendor.js, in the latest version of Angular using the Angular CLI?

Comment: I doubt it since every time when bundle created internal web pack references are changing.

Comment: You can use Webpack DLL